# Msi installer does not add the Outlook Addin

Tags: windows-installer, outlook-addin, setup-project

I've created an Outlook 2010 addin and a setup project to create and msi that would install the addin. 
On right-click and Install on the Setup project, I see the addIn in Outlook, but on clicking the XXX.msi file I fail to see the addIn in Outlook.
Another difference I see is on trying to install it using the XX.msi file it gets installed successfully and also see an entry of it in the ControlPanel - Programs and Features list.
On the contrary when I right-click and install, I do not see it in Programs and Features.

I've followed this link to create the setup project. Also changed the registry key from HKEY_USER to HKEY_MACHINE. - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/10/01/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-2-of-2.aspx 
Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why did you change it away from HKEY_USER? I believe Office is a user-based product, each user has their own choices.

Comment: The AddIn wouldn't display on startup of Outlook. So I've been trying out variations of the HKEY_XX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2012 Addin and the setup project works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The registry entries from the article linked are good. Check the architecture of your machine against the one of your MSI and version of Office installed. i.e if you have a x64 machine and install a x86 MSI, the registry entries will get created under "Wow6432Node" key.

If Office x64 is on that machine the registry entries created will not be visible. You will need a x64 MSI and the components of the registry entries marked as 64-bit, this way Windows Installer will not redirect the entries under "Wow6432Node" and any version of Office x64 should see them.

Comment: When I build the setup project in VS2010, the addIn gets added to Outlook. But when I install the AddIn using the .msi, it doesn't want to display on outlook.

Comment: Im using 32 bit OS and 32 bit MSOffice.

Comment: The only reason for which Office would not see the addin is if the registry entries you create with the MSI are not correctly defined or don't get created correctly (check them with regedit.exe). I've created dozens of MSIs for addins using this method and they always got loaded by the corespondent Office app.

Comment: This issue doesn't come up when creating an Addin in VS 2012 and a setup project with the same version. So for now, Im going with VS2012.